# Role centers/ Enterprise Portal show a script error for WEB content

Tags: axapta

We are trying to integrate an web page into Role Centers page. The role centers page works fine when when opened in IE but is showing an error when showing Role center page in AX Home:

[image]

Is there a way to fix it? Maybe JS needs to imported somewhere ?
or There is a way to stop to not show errors like these?

Comment: Do you have control over that web page you are trying to integrate?